# MvvmCross navigate to tab in tabbed view creates a new tab, Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have multiple tabs in Xamarin.iOS with MvvmCross, say Tab1, Tab2, Tab3. They are all included in the MainViewModel. I open a separate modal view with a view model - ModalViewModel. From ModalViewModel I need to navigate to Tab2ViewModel, while calling it like this:

```
 MvxNavigationService.Navigate<Tab2ViewModel>();
```

opens a new tab next to already existing ones, so it appears as MainViewModel with Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab2.
Is there a way to navigate to specific tab from unrelated ViewModel?
Is there a way to command to MainViewModel to open specific tab?

Answer (score 1):

For the lost souls out there, the solution was quite easy:

```
MvxNavigationService.ChangePresentation(new MvxPagePresentationHint(typeof(Tab2ViewModel)));
```

Be sure to close the current view if you are not in the MainViewModel like this:

```
MvxNavigationService.Close(this);
```

Comment: How do you pass a parameter when using MvxPagePresentationHint?